# How to have change debugger setting in Eclipse for a launch file

Tags: eclipse, gwt, ide, settings

His,

I have been trying to find out why starting DevMode with Debugger from Eclipse was so slow and noticed in the list of processes on my machine the following line:

/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_14/bin/java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:47248 ...

Apparently the application is suspended to wait until the debugger is connected which takes about 2 minutes. I would like to set "suspend=n". Does anyone know where I could set this directive. The vm section in Eclipse launch configuration is empty and if I paste the updated debugger config there is a error telling that the values are entered twice.

As I understand it, Eclipse takes this config from somewhere and inserts it automatically when I run launch configurations in debugger mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove that parameter and, if you could, it wouldn't make a difference. When you connect a new browser to the GWT OOPHM instance it has to compile the entire project for use in development mode. This is what takes time, not waiting for the debugger to attach.

Comment: I have compared times launching DevMode with Debugger and without and it definately faster to start it without debugger attached. For my project it takes like 2 extra minutes with debugger attached to start DevMode. So it definitely has to do with debugger configuration.

Comment: Do you have active breakpoints set? I have noticed that disabling/removing breakpoints during compilation slows things down.